# Ejecutar X tarea en cierta fecha mientras la página esté inactiva

Tags: php, email, schedule

Estoy intentando hacer un reporte quincenal, la idea es que la función que tengo se ejecute aunque la página está inactiva, ya tengo la función, lo que necesito es saber como hago para que esa función se ejecute mientras no haya actividad en el sistema.

Comment: tienes que.crear una tarea programada que ejecute el script, si estaás en windows puedes usar el programador de tareas, si estas en linux puedes configurar un cron

Comment: Simplemente añadir que para que no recargue más el servidor (para que se cumpla lo que pides de que ejecute cuando esté inactivo), configurar dicha tarea con prioridad baja